# How to pass sql row id into into a class (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, class, mysqli, parameters

The script below processes form data (multiple text fields, a radio button value and 2 file uploads). I have two sql statements within the script, one outside the php class CropAvatar that inserts the text fields to sql, another sql statement within the CropAvatar class that inserts the two file URL's to sql. I can't seem to make both sql statements work at the same time. I don't think I'm fully grasping how php classes work.

What is the best way to get both of these sql INSERT statements to function?

Additionally, both statements will need to **insert into the same row in sql**. I'm guessing I will need to define the id (which is auto increment) of the row and 'pass' it into the class. Incredibly confused.

Here's the script, thank you in advance:

```
<?php
    require('../dbcon.php');
    $title = $_POST['title'];$address = $_POST['address'];$sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];$lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];$build_size = $_POST['build_size'];$lot_size = $_POST['lot_size'];$zoning = $_POST['zoning'];$comment = $_POST['comment'];$transaction = $_POST['transaction'];
$sql="INSERT INTO listings ( title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment, transaction, date_added)
     VALUES ( '$title', '$address', '$lot_size', '$zoning', '$build_size', '$sale_price', '$lease_price', '$comment', '$transaction', now())";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
class CropAvatar {
    private $src;private $data;private $file;private $dst;private $type;private $extension;private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';private $msg;

    function __construct($src, $data, $file) {
        $this -> setSrc($src);
        $this -> setData($data);
        $this -> setFile($file);
        $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
    }
    private function setSrc($src) {
        if (!empty($src)) {
            $type = exif_imagetype($src);

            if ($type) {
                $this -> src = $src;
                $this -> type = $type;
                $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                $this -> setDst();
            }
        }
    }
    private function setData($data) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
        }
    }
    private function setFile($file) {
        $errorCode = $file['error'];
        if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
            if ($type) {
                $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                    mkdir($dir, 0777);
                }           
                $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;

                if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

                    if (file_exists($src)) {
                        unlink($src);
                    }

    $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);

    $listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
    $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
    $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
    $extensionf = end($tempf);

    if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
    && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
    && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
    {
    $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

    if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }   
    else 
    {
        if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
        {
         echo $_FILES["flyer"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
            else 
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
             }
    }
  $ad_link="http://www.wesbite.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
  require('../dbcon.php');
  $sql="INSERT INTO listings (listing_img, ad_link)
   VALUES ('$listing_img', '$ad_link',)";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);mysqli_close($con);
  }
                    if ($result) {
                        $this -> src = $src;$this -> type = $type;$this -> extension = $extension;$this -> setDst();
                    } else {
                         $this -> msg = 'Failed to save file';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
            }
        } else {
            $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
        }
    }
private function setDst() {
        $dir = $this -> dstDir;

        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }

        $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
    }
private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
        if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
            switch ($this -> type) {
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                    break;
            }
            if (!$src_img) {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                return;
            }
            $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
            $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
            if ($result) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                }
                if (!$result) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
            }
            imagedestroy($src_img);
            imagedestroy($dst_img);
        }
    }
    private function codeToMessage($code) {
        switch ($code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                break;
            default:
                $message = 'Unknown upload error';
        }
        return $message;
    }
    public function getResult() {
        return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
    }
    public function getMsg() {
        return $this -> msg;
    }
}
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file']);
$response = array(
    'state'  => 200,
    'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
    'result' => $crop -> getResult()
);

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You should really try to minimize the amount of code you post. Nobody wants to sort through 244 lines of mostly unrelated stuff.

Comment: completely agree @Mike I'm currently condensing. I'm sorry

Comment: I don't see the problem; you have 2 `INSERT` statements that insert in the same table. If you also want them to insert in the same row, simply combine them. And you should read up on sql injection.

Comment: @jeroen, if I combine them within the class CropAvatar, the text fields all post null, I'm guessing because executing the mysql_code inside the CropAvatar class will not work as the variables are outside of the scope of the class itself.

Comment: `$_POST` is a super-global so you can access it anywhere you want.

Comment: @jeroen If I execute sql inside the class, the variables are all null in the db

Comment: `$_POST` is global, but the variables you assign outside of your class are not.

Comment: @jeroen ok I see that now, how would I get those variables to post within the class?